# Вопрос как запустить java код на сервере?

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Задача такая, есть текст с кодом, нужно отправить его через POST на сервер, и виртуальная машина java должна его отработать и вернуть результат в виде текста на клиент. Может кто делал такое или знаком, куда копать с чего начать?

Comment: Написать программу на Java, которая поднимает веб-сервер (например: jetty, undertow, ratpack, rapidoid) и обрабатывает POST-запрос. Обрабатывает его и возвращает обратно.

Comment: @Nofate кажется, имеется в виду интерпретация голого java-кода

Comment: @Etki, тогда нужно на стороне сервера код скомпилировать [(это можно сделать программно)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) и написать `ClassLoader` который запустит этот код. Но  я тут вижу много проблем с безопасностью, мягко говоря.